# C++ * const *const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I tried to search answer for this but I found it very hard to find 'exact' example of this kind. I understand very little about pointers to pointers and I feel there is something more laying under the skin of this than just pointer to something.

So how would you guys translate this?

```
void free(shame_1 * const * const group_1);
```

Am I right if I translate it as const group_1 pointer to const pointer to shame_1?

Thanks.

Comment: `group_1` is  just the name of the variable. So the type of that variable is const pointer to const pointer to `shame_1`. The way the constness is defined here means you cannot change the value of `group_1`, nor that of `*group_1`, but you can change the value of `**group_1`.

Comment: If you have trouble reading C/C++ declaration, take a look at the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: A tip a colleague of mine gave me, that helps me a lot is: "Read the type from right to left". It solves a lot of confusion for now that I know that :)

Comment: Thank you guys very much for quick and accurate answers! Also thanks to answers under this post since I didn't want to use the answer button. I thought this site handles apprentices with rough hand but I was wrong. I will later post the correct answer when I melt this information in my head. I was also wondering if there is some kind of way to do this exact thing in C#? Thanks for that also if you don't mind to answer.

Comment: If your head is about to explode from seeing C gibberish, you can always fall back to [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/): `cdecl explain 'int * const * const group_1'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shame_1 * const * const group_1;
```

declares a variable named group_1, whose type is a const pointer (you cannot change where it points at) to another const pointer (same) to a shame_1-type object, whose value you can actually change.

So, for instance, you cannot compile:

```
group_1 = nullptr;
*group_1 = nullptr;
```

You can, however, do:

```
void f(shame_1& group) {
    //stuff that modifies group
    ...
}
f(**group1);
```

As zakinster commented, having a look at [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) should help you understand this kind of notation.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, just read from right to left:

```
void free(shame_1 * const * const group_1);
```

`free` takes a parameter called `group_1` that's a `const` pointer to a `const` pointer to a `shame_1` object.

- It's not relevant here, but the main hassle reading right-to-left is that some people use `T const *` and others use `const T*` and they mean the same thing, so whether you see either `T const` or `const T` you should read it as `const T`.  In your code, only the pointers are `const` anyway.

For example:

```
shame_1 a_shame;
const shame_1* p_a_shame = &a_shame;
free(&p_a_shame);
```

There's very little utility in this... `free()` could have accepted a `const` pointer to a `shame_1` without an extra level of indirection, and would still have been able to do all the same things to the `shame_1`, so it's only useful if `free()` has to pass the `const`-pointer-to-`const`-pointer to some other function (with ultimately there being no good reason for the whole mess).

You can visualise the memory usage / relationships as:

```
[a_shame]  <------ [p_a_shame]  <------  [group_1]*
```

- this is likely only in a CPU register, though the others may be too after optimisation.

> Am I right if I translate it as const group_1 pointer to const pointer to shame_1?

So, to me the "const group_1 pointer" bit is a bit suspect... I think it reads better as "group_1 is a const pointer to..." or "const pointer (called group_1) to...".